# fill border with pattern or image?

Tags: html, css, border, image

I have a list of businesses separated by categories. Next to each category name, starting at about 20px apart, I'd like to have a 3px tall border stretching to the end of the div. I would like for that border to be filled with a pattern, or image. Initially, I tried just using an image, but as each category name is a different length, that proved to be impractical.

I'm sure there is a relatively easy way to go about this, I'm just not certain on how to make it happen. Ideas?

Thanks.

[image: ideal]

updated image
[image]

Comment: Have you looking into CSS border-images? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-image

Comment: @j08691 That looks promising, thanks for pointing it out. I've edited a bit of the given code to suit my situation(and pasted it in my original question), but the border doesn't appear. Any ideas?

Comment: IE (10 included) has no support for `border-image` http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image

Comment: Aside from making sure your image exists at the path, and you've read the docs in the link above, check out the demo at http://border-image.com where you can play with a live example.

Comment: ah, was lining the border with the logo instead of category, try this instead, http://jsfiddle.net/DhbtV/10/, I've added some markup `vendor-category` with the `h2` and border nested with some style changes

Comment: @mdmullinax way to save the day, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here I'm using a `<div>` to show the border behind the `<h1>` *category* where both the `<body>` and `<h1>` have matching background patterns (that are also lined up)

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xc3y5/2/)

CSS

```css
body {
    background:url('http://subtlepatterns.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/gray_jean.png');
    font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
}

#container {
    margin:0 20px;
    position:relative;
}

h1 {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-right:20px;
    font-size:2em;
    background:url('http://subtlepatterns.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/gray_jean.png')
}

.border {
    background:url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/creattica/uploaded-images/0016/6142/patterns_009_blue-hexagon-pattern_crop-iphone_web_for-creattica.jpg') repeat-x -10px 0;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    width:100%;
    height:3px;
}

.listings {
    clear:both;
}
​
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="border"></div>
    <h1>Catering</h1>
    <div class="listings">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Catering Company 1
            </li>
            <li>
                ...
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I've tried implementing them in my site(which unfortunately isn't live, yet) with little luck. I've created a JSFiddle, if you wouldn't mind taking a look..

http://jsfiddle.net/DhbtV/

Comment: see: http://jsfiddle.net/DhbtV/1/ I've made some comments in the CSS for what was changed, also moved the border div above the logo

Comment: So close! I've attached an updated image to my original question. It seems all content has been pushed below the logo, whereas it should be next to it. Advise? Thanks!

Comment: should be a matter of removing the `clear:both` from `#vendor-list .vendor h2` and upping the `padding-top` to push the content under the border http://jsfiddle.net/DhbtV/4/

Comment: removing `clear:both` helped a lot. Is there a way for the border to appear next to `h2`, instead of above or below?

Answer (score 0):

If additional markup is allowed (and your parent element has a solid background), you could go about it this way:

```
h1 {
    background: red; /* replace with background-image */
}

h1 span {
    background: white; /* replace with color of parent element's bg */
}

<h1><span>Test Headline</span></h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/358Gg/

Comment: I'm using an image from subtlepatterns.com as a background. Is there a work around for this?